# How to align text next to a div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible when using css to make text align right next to a div. I'm not sure how to explain it so here is an example of what i would like. Thanks.

```
    DIV TAG text text text text
    DIV TAG text text text text
    DIV TAG text text text text
    text text text text text
    text text text text text
    text text text text text
    text text text text text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#article {
    width: 200px;
}

#floating {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #f00;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<p id="article">
    <div id="floating">&nbsp;</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much, I can't believe I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inl {
    display: inline;   
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='inl'>div</div> text text text text<br/>
<div class='inl'>div</div> text text text text<br/>
<div class='inl'>div</div> text text text text<br/>
text text text text text<br/>
text text text text text<br/>
text text text text text<br/>
text text text text text<br/>
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it does not work when the div height is bigger than the height of the line. Here is what happens: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RuRh7/7/)